# javascript stops after document.getelementbyid

Tags: javascript, alert, getelementbyid

Hei!

```
var arrFolders=['2006','2007','2008'];
body.getElementById("folders").innerHTML="";
alert("ok");
```

When i run this code the alert does not run. I have a div with id 'folders'. Does anyone know why this javascript stops on getElementById???

Comment: **document**.getElementById

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) is defined on the document and you might not even have a `body` variable (it's a property of `document`, not of `window`).

Change

```
body.getElementById("folders")
```

to

```
document.getElementById("folders")
```

But you **must** learn how to spot those bugs, by [using the console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) which lists errors. And using `alert(something)` is a terribly painful way to track your bugs, use `console.log(something)`.

Comment: hear hear @ 'use the console'